# How to edit or delete table data of database from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate

Hi i have an ajax jquery function which displays table data as shown in the picture, i want to add a field which says edit and delete which gives the user the permission to edit or delete table data and it will get reflected in the database. Please note i have not given any index value to the response data nor an id
is there any way to achieve this! if so could you please explain or show me references! thanx!

[image]

```js
 $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> <input type='checkbox',  value='" + response.data[i].electrician_email + "'>"+response.data[i].electrician_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].electrician_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].electrician_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].electrician_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a simple manner, like add a number to the row and edit the row using the rownumber. Here is the code what I have tried and hope it helps you.

like see the code snippet here

```
<tr id="row1">
<td id="name_row1">XXX</td>
<td id="country_row1">India</td>
<td id="age_row1">20</td>
<td>
<input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
<input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
</td>
</tr>
```

There in the `tr` id is row1, when you add a new row a new `tr` is created with id rowX `X` is a number. If you want to edit the row, select the row using `rowX` and edit or delete whatever you want.

```js
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";
 
 var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no);
 var country=document.getElementById("country_row"+no);
 var age=document.getElementById("age_row"+no);
 
 var name_data=name.innerHTML;
 var country_data=country.innerHTML;
 var age_data=age.innerHTML;
 
 name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+name_data+"'>";
 country.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='country_text"+no+"' value='"+country_data+"'>";
 age.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+no+"' value='"+age_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var name_val=document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value;
 var country_val=document.getElementById("country_text"+no).value;
 var age_val=document.getElementById("age_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("name_row"+no).innerHTML=name_val;
 document.getElementById("country_row"+no).innerHTML=country_val;
 document.getElementById("age_row"+no).innerHTML=age_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}

function add_row()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var new_country=document.getElementById("new_country").value;
 var new_age=document.getElementById("new_age").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_country+"</td><td id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_age+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_country").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_age").value="";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>

<tr id="row1">
<td id="name_row1">XXX</td>
<td id="country_row1">India</td>
<td id="age_row1">20</td>
<td>
<input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
<input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="row2">
<td id="name_row2">YYY</td>
<td id="country_row2">Australia</td>
<td id="age_row2">78</td>
<td>
<input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
<input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_country"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_age"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complicated and that can't be answered in a few lines of code.

You may restart from scratch by looking at this old CRUD: http://jtable.org/

Or angular x-editable (using bootstrap):
https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row